# Borrowing class method from another class (Python 3)

Tags: python, class-method

Borrowing the implementation of an instance method from another class is straightforward, but how do I do it with a class method?

```
class A:
  def im(self):
    print(self.__class__.__name__)

  @classmethod
  def cm(cls):
    print(cls.__name__)

class B:
  im = A.im
  cm = A.cm # line X
  classmethod(cm)

B().im() # B - OK
B.cm() # A - not what I want
```

I also tried changing line X into `cm = A.cm.__func__`, which caused `TypeError: cm() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls'`

Answer (score 4):

When you access `A.cm`, you invoke the `classmethod` object as a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), which means it is already bound to the `A` class. Unwrap it again:

```
class B:
    cm = classmethod(A.cm.__func__)
```

The `.__func__` attribute gives you access to the original function, so you can rewrap it with a new `classmethod` call.

Alternatively, use the `A.__dict__` mapping to get the actual classmethod itself, bypassing the descriptor calls:

```
class B:
    cm = A.__dict__['cm']
```

Comment: That alternative looks quite intriguing, but also somehow dirty.

Comment: It is the only way to prevent the descriptor protocol from kicking in; it is there mostly for illustration.

Answer (score 3):

You need:

```
class B:
  im = A.im
  cm = classmethod(A.cm.__func__)
```

When you access `A.cm`, the resulting classmethod already "knows" that it belongs to A.  If you want to rewrap it for a different class, you need to extract the underlying function with `__func__` and then rewrap it with `classmethod`.

Also, in your example, the line `classmethod(cm)` does nothing, because you don't assign the result to anything.

Comment: Ah! So I was right to change line X the way I did - only I also should have changed the following line into `cm = classmethod(cm)`.

Comment: @Heny'Pi'James: Yeah, that would have the same effect as my solution.